# Compare 2 column in a same SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, heidisql

I want to compare values from 2 distinct column in a SQL table.

```
A ---------------- B
10 -------------- 88
20 -------------- 401
30 -------------- 20
40 -------------- 99
```

I want to keep the values ​​of the second column that are equal to the values ​​of the first column (as 20), but also those that contain a value of the first column (as 401 which contains 40).

So in this example I would see a column C with :

```
A ---------------- B ----------------- C
10 -------------- 88 ---------------- No
20 -------------- 401 -------------- Yes
30 -------------- 20 ---------------- Yes
40 -------------- 99 ---------------- No
```

in fact, I can compare fields in the same row but not apply this comparison to all fields in a column.

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll need to use subqueries to compare outside of the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a nested `select` and a `case` statement.  The nested select uses `like` to see if there are any rows that meet the similarity condition.  Note that the `like` will find a match if the values are identical as well as when the `B` column starts with the `A` column:

```
select t.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from table t2 where t1.B like concat(t2.A, '%'))
             then 'Yes'
             else 'No'
        end) as C
from table t;
```

EDIT:

If by contain, you want `'1401'` to also match `'40'`, then the pattern for the `like` should be: `concat('%', t2.A, '%')`.

Comment: Need to wrap both sides with `%` - OP is looking for values that *contain* not simply *start with*

Comment: @SetSailMedia . . . I'm not sure the OP is using *contain* in that sense, but I added a note into the answer.